# CSS : how to add extra length to background color

Tags: css

i have added background color to text but i want to add a bit more black color on start and it end of string so that its readable better. But

**sample code**

```
<div class="row" style="background-color: black; color: white; display: inline; font-weight: bold;">   12345678890   </div>
```

so this looks like

[image]

however i want to add extra color it start and end like this

[image]

so any idea how to do it , i tried with adding blank spaces to string but it not working

Comment: you can add `padding` like this: `padding: 0 10px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use padding

```html
    <div class="row" style="padding:0 5px; background-color: black; color: white; display: inline; font-weight: bold;"> 12345678890
    </div>
```

2. You can use `&nbsp;`

```html
    <div class="row" style="background-color: black; color: white; display: inline; font-weight: bold;">&nbsp; 12345678890 &nbsp;
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" style="padding:0 10px; background-color: black; color: white; display: inline; font-weight: bold;">   12345678890   </div>
```

Just add a little padding. It work for your case

Answer (score 0):

Adding left and right padding to the div could help you in this. Try this :-

```
<div class="row" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; background-color: black; color: white; display: inline; font-weight: bold;">   12345678890   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use padding-left and padding-right.
e.g.

```
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding-left.asp

Comment: ya but padding right will take the color to new row

Comment: it sould not - maybe you are giving it to much on the right side; you could replicate your issue here: https://codepen.io/pen/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: Please have a look into it.
https://web-platform-tjjnkh.stackblitz.io

**Note**: If you're using a bootstrap then you can use a class like px-value and py-value where value is from 1-5.